# Manually tell GDB the address at which executable is loaded

Tags: gdb

I have a C++ application where somehow, gdb (I'm using the mingw-w64 version) always seems to be confused about what address the main executable is loaded at. If I try to insert a breakpoint on some function or file+line number, gdb tries to do it at the wrong address and the breakpoint doesn't work. It also can't produce backtraces. I can see that the address it uses is wrong by adding a `printf` showing the address of some function, and comparing it with the one gdb uses with `break someFunction` (or `print &someFunction`). On the other hand, for functions located in DLLs, gdb can successfully insert a breakpoint or produce a backtrace (at least until a function in the executable is reached).

I don't know why this happens, but it would be nice to be able to use the debugger anyway. Assuming the hypothesis of a wrong address for the executable's code segment, is there some way I can adjust it to be at the right place? The gdb versions I've tried are 7.9 and 8.0.1.

Comment: How did you compile your C++ application? Show the exact compilation commands (and tell more about the compiler version). BTW, `gdb-8.1` works quite well on Linux, so did you consider developing your application on some Linux distro? Better yet, provide in your question some small [MCVE] -a small piece of C++- exhibiting the same symptom (and give *exactly* the compilation commands used to build it). Without that practical information, your question is unclear...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yeah, the application runs on Linux as well, but maybe I want to debug the Windows version? As for exactly how it's compiled, it's not so easy to say in this comment box; there are hundreds of files and a load of CMake configuration.

Comment: So, work a few hours to provide an [MCVE] to exhibit the same problem. Perhaps your Cmake thing did not pass some `-g` flag to `g++`; without such additional -but *essential*- details, your question is unclear (since nobody can reproduce your problem even on his PC running Windows 10 & gdb-8.1)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm not asking anyone to debug the issues with the binary, just a simple question of whether it's possible to specify what address to add.

Comment: But you cannot get useful help without any [MCVE] and *detailed* instructions on how you compiled it (including the compiler, its options, its version). BTW, did you read carefully the [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't understand. I want to know if a certain command or feature exists in gdb. Why do I need an MCVE for that?

Comment: To know which commands exist in `gdb`, read carefully its [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) manual and notice that some GDB can be [extended](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html) with scripts in Guile or in Python. To check that you compile your code correctly for debugging, provide some [MCVE]. I'm guessing (perhaps wrongly, just a guess) that you are compiling your code incorrectly.

Comment: Sounds like you have ASLR enabled for your executable.

Comment: @ssbssa This is the hint I needed. I assumed ASLR could not be on since the addresses were the same every time I built the executable, but what there was is a botched attempt to enable ASLR (dynamicbase but not high entropy va flags). This was enough to confuse gdb, but not enough to actually randomize the addresses.

Comment: If you used dynamicbase, then the addresses should be randomized. high-entropy-va means just more entropy for the random addresses.